# How to get dynamic current path in express router

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

```js
router.get('/add/:id', (req, res, next) => {
        let productId = req.params.id;
        let cart = new Cart(req.session.cart ? req.session.cart : {});
        
        cart.addByOne(productId);
        req.session.cart = cart;
        
        // the path name below should be dynamic
        res.redirect('/shopping-cart');
        res.redirect('/checkout');
    });

router.get('/shopping-cart', (req, res, next) => {
    if(!req.session.cart) {
        return res.render('shopping-cart', {products: null});
    }
    let cart = new Cart(req.session.cart);
    res.render('shopping-cart', {products: cart.generateArray(), totalPrice: cart.totalPrice});
});

router.get('/checkout', isLoggedIn, (req, res, next) => {
    if (!req.session.cart) {
      return res.redirect('/shopping-cart');
    }

    let cart = new Cart(req.session.cart);
    res.render('checkout', {products: cart.generateArray(), total: cart.totalPrice});  
});
```

The redirected path name should be dynamic, meaning that if the current local path name is for example http://localhost:5002/shopping-cart is should be res.redirect('/shopping-cart');

If localhost name http://localhost:5002/checkout, it should be changed to res.redirect('/checkout') and so on. Is there a way to change that dynamically, and keep that code clean as possible. The routers are defined and the files checkout.ejs and shopping-cart.ejs.

Comment: how you have defined the route for /shopping-cart?

Comment: I found it after looking through the documentation again. What I was looking for were the __filename and __dirname module-level variables.

Comment: @AZ_ Hey Goku.... :)

Comment: both are defined the routers and views: checkout.ejs and shopping-cart.ejs.

Comment: @frontend you can use `res.render('shopping-cart')`

Answer (score 0):

```js
let currentUrl; 

router.get('/add/:id', (req, res, next) => {
    let productId = req.params.id;
    let cart = new Cart(req.session.cart ? req.session.cart : {});

    cart.addByOne(productId);
    req.session.cart = cart;
    res.redirect(currentUrl);
});

router.get('/shopping-cart', (req, res, next) => {
    if(!req.session.cart) {
        return res.render('shopping-cart', {products: null});
    }

    currentUrl = '/shopping-cart';

    let cart = new Cart(req.session.cart);
    res.render('shopping-cart', {products: cart.generateArray(), totalPrice: cart.totalPrice});
    console.log('shopping-cart' + url);
});

router.get('/checkout', isLoggedIn, (req, res, next) => {
    if (!req.session.cart) {
      return res.redirect('/shopping-cart');
    }

    currentUrl = '/checkout';

    let cart = new Cart(req.session.cart);
    res.render('checkout', {products: cart.generateArray(), total: cart.totalPrice});  
});
```

By making a global variable named currentUrl, I store the current path name here, so every time when the router loads it will look for a new updated currentUrl.

Comment: The `currentUrl` variable should be a part of a session, otherwise, every user will be able to influence the value of `currentUrl` for every other user.

Comment: What did you mean? Like req.session.currentUrl?

Comment: Sorry for not being clearer. Yes, with `req.session`. Then each user who has established a session will have their own `currentUrl` value.